# How to get field value in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I have a function that outputs all `Product` data to the `data array`, but I also need to display 5 products from the same `category` in the `relatives array`.

Function:

```
func GetProductsById(c *gin.Context) { 
    var Product models.Products
    Products := []models.Products{}

    config.DB.Where("cat_id", func(tx *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        return config.DB.Where("id=?", c.Query("prod_id")).Select("cat_id").First(&Product)
    }).Find(&Products)

    if err := config.DB.Where("id=?", c.Query("prod_id")).First(&Product).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "data":      []models.Products{Product},
            "relatives": &Products})
    }
}
```

I tried to do it myself, but I can't access the `product category` from the data array to show 5 similar products.
And i have error:
`cannot convert 0xa182e0 to Int8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your id is integer, and c.Query("prod_id") returns string. you must be cast it to integer by

```
intVar, err := strconv.Atoi(c.Query("prod_id"))
```

if code has not error:

```
config.DB.Where("cat_id", func(tx *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return config.DB.Where("id=?", intVar).Select("cat_id").First(&Product)
}).Find(&Products)
```